# Plotting three lines on the same plot (with 4-hour frequency)

Tags: python, pandas, plotting

I want to plot the graph with datetime . I saw so many questions similiar to my questions. But that answers didn't work for me. Here is the code that I used:

```
 data = pd.read_csv('p1.csv')
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['date', 'time', 'x1', 'x2','x3'])
 data['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + ' ' + data['time'])
data['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
data.set_index('date_time',inplace = True)
plt.plot(data.index, data.x2)
```

Plot graph :
[image]

Can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

CSV file after reading it:

[image]

I want to plot like this but with date:
[image]

Comment: Can you please add the full dataframe(what 'data' looks like)?

Comment: @yoav_aaa I added the image of the dataframe and I changed the code also

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to plot three different lines with a 4-hour interval, you will need to resample your data. (This is how you get your frequency conversion). You can read about that more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

```
pd.resample()
```

Then as long as all three of your "lines" are contained in the same data frame, you should have no problem plotting them by just calling

```
three_lines = your data frame

plt.plot(three_lines)
```

Although one note - just looking at your data, you might not get the desired result given the scale difference in your data. Said a different way, the values < 1 might be minimally visible when plotted on the same figure as values ranging around 100.

Hope this helps. Please drop a comment if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the great wxplanation . I have a question, If I have date series I mean 8/6/2018 I have a dataset and then I have a dataset 9/6/2018, then again I have a datset 10/6/2018. So how I can write date_range ?

Comment: Yes , I'm also stuck with this error.

Comment: So to clarify, there is no time overlap between any of the data points you wish to plot?

Comment: to get the idea i upload the pic like what i want to plot